# Fast repeated row counting in vast data - what format?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, csv

My Node.js app needs to index several gigabytes of timestamped CSV data, in such a way that it can quickly get the row count for any combination of values, either for each minute in a day (1440 queries) or for each hour in a couple of months (also 1440). Let's say in half a second.

The column values will not be read, only the row counts per interval for a given permutation. Reducing time to whole minutes is OK. There are rather few possible values per column, between 2 and 10, and some depend on other columns. It's fine to do preprocessing and store the counts in whatever format suitable for this single task - *but what format would that be?*

Storing actual values is probably a bad idea, with millions of rows and little variation.

It might be feasible to generate a short code for each combination and match with regex, but since these codes would have to be duplicated each minute, I'm not sure it's a good approach.

Or it can use an embedded database like SQLite, NeDB or TingoDB, but am not entirely convinced since they don't have native enum-like types and might or might not be made for this kind of counting. But maybe it would work just fine?

This must be a common problem with an idiomatic solution, but I haven't figured out what it might be called. Knowing what to call this and how to think about it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will answer with my own findings for now, but I'm still interested to know more theory about this problem.

NeDB was not a good solution here as it saved my values as normal JSON behind the hood, repeating key names for each row and adding unique IDs. It wasted lots of space and would surely have been too slow, even if just because of disk I/O.

SQLite might be better at compressing and indexing data, but I have yet to try it. Will update with my results if I do.

Instead I went with the other approach I mentioned: assign a unique letter to each column value we come across and get a short string representing a permutation. Then for each minute, add these strings as keys iff they occur, with the number of occurrences as values. We can later use our dictionary to create a regex that matches any set of combinations, and run it over this small index very quickly.

This was easy enough to implement, but would of course have been trickier if I had had more  possible column values than the about 70 I found.